# Standard "Works for me" input field

Tags: feature-request, comments, design

A frequent comment in Stack Overflow is "works for me", followed by a link to jsfiddle, sqlfiddle, IDEone, etc. that demonstrates that the code works (i.e. it doesn't have the problem that the questioner says it has). Example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874809/all-elements-animating-when-only-one-should

It would be nice if there were a standard input field that could be filled in with the link, rather than doing this as a comment.

Some potential benefits are:

- Just a single entry could be allowed, so we don't get lots of duplicate comments.
- Statistics could be generated from them, to help determine question quality.
- It can produce a standard comment message, like Close-as-duplicate does.

Comment: What benefit would that add over the simple comment?

Comment: I think what he's saying is he uses the comment to say the problem the OP has doesn't appear to exist. So he wouldn't upvote, but rather downvote or close as couldn't be reproduced

Answer (score 9):

There's a better way to handle this already. Flag to close as off-topic with the following sub-reason:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: That's possible, but often the problem is that the poster hasn't included all relevant details, and comments will tease these out before the question is put on hold.

Comment: @Barmar Then leave a comment asking for more details. Or choose a different close reason ("unclear what you're asking" or "off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem" would apply fairly well). This doesn't really need a special field that isn't also applicable to most other sites in the network.

Comment: If you want to engage in a conversation with the asker to help them form a better question, do so. All the tools you need for that are already in place. If you don't, vote/flag to close and/or move on to another question.

Comment: If you use the `off-topic` close reason, where would you put the link to the demonstration that the problem can't be reproduced? That's what I'm suggesting should be standardized, just like the link to a duplicate is standard in close-as-duplicate.

Comment: @Barmar What I'm saying is that it doesn't need a complex standard system. Just leave a comment. (As an aside, we hesitate to include external dependencies. If, say, a jsfiddle link was required for a close reason, we'd be very unlikely to implement that since we have no control over jsfiddle's uptime. For example.)